# Device only reading a voltage on tester when touched.

Tags: voltage

I have a client that has a pair of class 2 sewing machines that have a metal plate which keeps giving them a small shock.

Having tested them both they are showing 0v when the machin is on. At least this is the case until the same metal component is touched at which point both machines read around 30v.

Any idea on the cause?

Comment: Inside the sewing machine there's probably a short from the circuit board to that metal plate.

Comment: Are the sewing machine correctly earthed? I.e. has the power cord an earth-ground connection? (has the plug a third prong/terminal?). Moreover, is GFCI (ground fault current interrupter) installed in the system?

Comment: So you measured 0V but to what reference point - where was the other end of the meter connected?

Comment: Both machines are identical class 2 electrical devices, so have no capacity for an earth connection.

Comment: Tester connected to an earthed radiator.

Answer (score 1):

So you meant IEC class II (i.e. double insulated), not class 2 ([no, they aren't the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II)).

In this case there must be a fault somewhere, since in double insulated appliances any exposed metal parts should be floating. Citing Wikipedia:

> The basic requirement is that no single failure can result in dangerous voltage becoming exposed so that it might cause an electric shock and that this is achieved without relying on an earthed metal casing.

Unless the metal plate is energized from some unwanted external connection, the machines have some internal fault. Since both machines give the shock, I suspect they aren't properly designed as class II devices (it is unlikely that both machines failed in the same way, unless they are old and the fault developed in different time periods).

A professional electrician should inspect the connections to mains and a qualified technician should troubleshoot the machines: mains can kill, and such a symptom could foreshadow much worse outcomes, depending on how the internal construction of the machines is and the nature of the fault.